# Highcharts - Export Multiple Charts to Multi Page PDF File

Tags: pdf, charts, highcharts

We are using Highcharts for our charting application. We are displaying 16 bar charts on a webpage. We need to provide exporting feature (a button) through which all charts on the page get exported to a PDF file.

We have implemented it using the hack suggested on the Highcharts website. http://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/frequently-asked-questions#export-multiplesamples/highcharts/exporting/multiple-charts/.

However,when we export it, all 16 charts are coming on a single page in pdf. We want page breaks so that 4 charts can be shown on each page.

Is there any way we can achieve this ? Please help.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Related Highcharts [github ticket](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/5834).

Comment: Hi Pawel. I have added that ticket. Thank you for adding it here. Can you tell me if there is any alternate solution to this  ? I am not sure, how long it will take to add this feature on highchart export server. It's a kind of urgent now.

Comment: You can setup your own [exporting server](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/setting-up-the-server) and modify how [converting script](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-export-server/blob/master/java/highcharts-export/highcharts-export-convert/src/main/resources/phantomjs/highcharts-convert.js) works. Here is the line for setting [paperSize](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-export-server/blob/master/java/highcharts-export/highcharts-export-convert/src/main/resources/phantomjs/highcharts-convert.js#L217).