# Export multiple chart into pdf using highchart api each in separate pages

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts, export-to-pdf

Can anyone help me how to export multiple charts from highchart and export the charts into pdf. Each chart in different pdf pages.

Comment: Take a look at the comments from this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40055750/highcharts-export-multiple-charts-to-multi-page-pdf-file

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)